# Observable.concat with Exception

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have 2 data sources: DB and server. When I start the application, I call the method from the repository (MyRepository):

```
public Observable<List<MyObj>> fetchMyObjs() {
    Observable<List<MyObj>> localData = mLocalDataSource.fetchMyObjs();
    Observable<List<MyObj>> remoteData = mRemoteDataSource.fetchMyObjs();
    return Observable.concat(localData, remoteData);
}
```

I subscribe to it as follows:

```
mMyRepository.fetchMyObjs()         
            .compose(applySchedulers())
            .subscribe(
                    myObjs -> {
                        //do somthing
                    },
                    throwable ->  {
                        //handle error
                    }
            );
```

I expect that the data from the database will be loaded faster, and when the download of data from the network is completed, I will simply update the data in Activity.

When the Internet is connected, everything works well. But when we open the application without connecting to the network, then `mRemoteDataSource.fetchMyObjs();` throws `UnknownHostException` and on this all Observable ends (the subscriber for `localData` does not work (although logs tell that the data from the database was taken)). And when I try to call the `fetchMyObjs()` method again from the MyRepository class (via SwipeRefresh), the subscriber to `localData` is triggered.

How can I get rid of the fact that when the network is off, when the application starts, does the subscriber work for `localData`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some of error handling operators:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators

I'd guess onErrorResumeNext( ) will be fine but you have to test it by yourself. Maybe something like this would work for you:

```
Observable<List<MyObj>> remoteData = mRemoteDataSource.fetchMyObjs()
      .onErrorResumeNext()
```

Addidtionally I am not in position to judge if your idea is right or not but maybe it's worth to think about rebuilding this flow. It is not the right thing to ignore errors - that's for sure ;)

Comment: Than maybe try adding doOnError call

Comment: This seems like the right answer (provided you add something to the resume next:  `.onErrorResumeNext(ignored -> Observable.empty())`. If this doesn't work, can you say what the error is @osip_000?

Answer (score 0):

You can observe your chain with [observeOn(Scheduler scheduler, boolean delayError)](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#observeOn-io.reactivex.Scheduler-boolean-) and *delayError* set to **true**.

> delayError - indicates if the onError notification may not cut ahead of onNext notification on the other side of the scheduling boundary. If true a sequence ending in onError will be replayed in the same order as was received from upstream